# graph of transfer function for RC filter

Tags: filter

In an answer to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/11515/novice-question-about-low-pass-filter) Leon Heller links to a tutorial which includes the following graph:
[image]
I'm a bit confused. Shouldn't the graph for an RC filter monotonously decrease, without the inflection point?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The graph is correct. The curve looks a bit unusual because the voltage scale is linear. The Bode plot will have a slope of 6dB/octave which will be a straight line on a logarithmic graph. But a straight line on a logarithmic graph is a hyperbola on a semi-logarithmic graph.
If the curve were to approach a decreasing asymptote the voltage would eventually become negative. Not something you get from a divider.